# extjs 5.1 возврат данных success в формате JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, extjs

Всем доброго времени суток. Подскажите пожалуйста как решить следующую задачу. Столкнулся с extjs 5.1, ранее не работал с ним.

Вопрос в следующем есть такой интерфейс:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Реализовываю поиск учеников через AJAX.
Есть такой код:

```js
Ext.Ajax.request({
  url: '/admin/learner/getLearnerBySearch',
  params: {
    search: inputSearch.rawValue
  },
  waitMsg: 'Загрузка...',
  success: function(data) {
    //????.html(data.responseText); Как тут быть?
  }
});
```

Данным кодом я отдаю значение поиска в контроллер, вытягиваю запросом нужных людей в формате JSON получаю такую строку:

```js
[{
  "id": 16,
  "fio": "\u041a\u043b\u0438\u043c\u043e\u0432\u0430 \u0412\u0430\u043b\u0435\u0440\u0438\u044f",
  "email": "ms.klg4545453@mail.ru",
  "phone": "+7(920)31445459",
  "group": "244",
  "block": 0
}]
```

Теперь вопрос, в какой элемент в extjs вставить эту строку в success, чтоб появились в окошке представленном выше те записи, которые пришли из контроллера и все правильно отработало.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам не надо делать Ext.Ajax.request запрос для Grid. У него есть Store для этого.
В обработчике поиска делаете примерно так:

```
grig.getStore().addFilter({property: 'any', value: inputSearch.rawValue, operator: 'like'});
grid.getStore().loadPage(1); // если autoLoad: false
```

У store для этого должен быть конфиг `remoteFilter: true`.
Метод addFilter: https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.3/api/Ext.data.Store.html#method-addFilter

В результате Store будет загружаться с сервера с параметром:

```
filter:[{"property":"any","value":"keyword","operator":"like"}]
```

Который уже на сервере разберете и отфильтруете.

Но можно и просто добавить параметр к загрузке:

```
grid.getStore().getProxy().setExtraParam('search', inputSearch.rawValue);
grid.getStore().loadPage(1);
```

Тогда на сервер улетит запрос с параметром: `?search=...`

Comment: Спасибо, работает.